# Request/response handling in javax.servlet.filter class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

How to detect if it is a request/response the filter class is going to handle? Also I need to cancel the request to my servlet and want to create my own response and return it from dofilter method. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: please clarify what do you want to do

Answer (score 2):

Each filter can affect none, one, or both of the request and response.  It all depends upon if you do anything before and/or after calling `chain.doFilter(...)` - and if you pass in a wrapped request and/or response.

If you need to create your own response within the filter, simply don't call `chain.doFilter(...)` and provide your own response from the filter.

Please refer to the [`Filter.doFilter` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain%29), including:

> A typical implementation of this method would follow the following
>   pattern:-
>   1. Examine the request
>   2. Optionally wrap the request object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for input filtering
>   3. Optionally wrap the response object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for output filtering
>   4. a) Either invoke the next entity in the chain using the FilterChain object (chain.doFilter()),
>   4. b) or not pass on the request/response pair to the next entity in the filter chain to block the request processing
>   5. Directly set headers on the response after invocation of the next entity in the filter chain.

Comment: How can I implement a filter just for the request?

Answer (score 0):

I have mofied the response using response.getWriter().write("response data"); 
And avoided the response from passing to the servlet by removing that chain.doFilter();

Now, I am validating session variables(for authentication) from doFilter method. 
Since both requests and response are handling in same doFilter method, I think these session validation is happening 2 times (1.) while request happens & (2.) while reponse. 
But, how to find what doFilter is currently handling (request /response)?
So i can make session validation happen only at request time.

Comment: [This link](http://punekaramit.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/intercepting-http-response-using-servlet-filter/) explains when we handle request and resonse in filter